# How to send variables to ARM template maintemplate.json input?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I have an azure web application that creates application registration on azure portal and generates client id and client secret. I want to pass the generated client id and client secret of that application into the input parameter of mainTemplate.json file of my ARM template. Is there any direct/indirect way to send the variables from web app to ARM template or to fetch these variables by ARM template from the created application or from a temporary storage where these variables can be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since especially the client secret is a sensitive value, I'd recommend the following:

- You Web App generates the app registration
- It puts the client secret (and probably also the client id) into a Key Vault for safe storage
- Your ARM template [references the values from Key Vault secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli) and retrieves them at deployment time

Comment: Hi Thank You for your answer. I was just trying [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-powershell#reference-secrets-with-static-id) out on custom template deployment in azure but it shows that "This is not a valid template".

Comment: Well then then there is obviously something wrong with your template... but the approach generally works and is proven